# Как создать приложение в котором открывается конкретный сайт?

Tags: php, android, apk

Ребят приветствую.

У меня есть конструктор сайтов, на котором пользователи могут создавать свои сайты. Часто просят чтобы к этим сайтам можно было создавать еще и приложение.
Приложение максимально простое. Просто чтобы это приложение открывало сайт который указывает пользователь.

Вопрос, если ли какие-то API или библиотеки чтобы по кнопке генерировалось и скачивалось приложение. Сайт на PHP(Laravel).

Заранее премного благодарен.

Comment: нет такой возможности

Comment: Если есть сайты, которые конвертируют сайт в приложение, значит такая возможность есть, наверняка.

Answer (score 1):

Есть специальные возможности для реализации такого приложения. Гуглите Trusted Web Activity. [Пример на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/450506/)